# node.js setting a global variable

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node js. I searched a lot on stack overflow on this question below, none what I need.

I have an app.js file which initiates node server and a router file. I want to be able to store a global value once and shared across other server side .js files which contains my functions. I also want this variable to be accessible in my .jade file. (I use express BTW)

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, declare it outside the scope of your routes. Globals are a bad idea by the way, with JavaScript and NodeJS, globals can mess up things when you have multiple people using your app.

Comment: Use case - let's say I want to detect if the client is using PC or mobile. I execute a function to determine this one but I don't want to waste processing time evaluating this for every page request... Is there an easier way to accomplish this then?

Comment: Declaring a variable outside the scope of your routes does not make it global. Unlike the browser, the default scope in Node.js is module-level.

Answer (score 4):

The Node.js documentation says under [Module Caching](http://www.nodejs.org/api/modules.html#module_caching)

> **Caching** Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will
>   get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.
>
> Multiple calls to require('foo') may not cause the module code to be
>   executed multiple times. This is an important feature. With it,
>   "partially done" objects can be returned, thus allowing transitive
>   dependencies to be loaded even when they would cause cycles.
>
> If you want to have a module execute code multiple times, then export
>   a function, and call that function.

Which means you can easily expose a global object simply by putting it in its own module.

```
//config.js
var config = {
   dbUrl: 'mogodb://localhost:2107/persons'
};

module.exports = config;
```

And then when you want to gain access to that object, you simply do:

```
var config = require('./config');
```

And that's done, you get access to the same instance everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to limit the usage of global vars in Node. This is because unlike any other server side language, Node is a persistent process that share all request. So you cannot setup user state globally as those will be shared across all user accessing your site.

In raw node, there's two global context:

```
global.foo = 'bar';
// and the process object
process.some_var = 1;
```

In Express, you can setup application wide vars [using `app.set`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.set)

But, most of the time you'll want to share data by adding them to the `request` or the `response` objects. That is because those objects are "user" specifics, unlike the global namespace.

For the template, you'll always want to pass in the context:

```
app.render('email', Object.assign( aSharedObject, {
  specific: 'values'
}));
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, I want to store user's session specific information. How do I add this to req object so I can access it throughout the session.

Comment: Like any JS property: `req.some_property = "some value"`. Although, note that using session would be a better use case for an Express middleware.

Answer (score 0):

i would use process.env or if you are using nconf put it into the app configuration as Jordan said, globals are BAD idea, also if you don't want to include nconf or any other conf module or use process.env then you can create a module and export a set of getters and setters to handle the value